# How to access variables from private static inner class

Tags: java, reflection

I've a class structure like this:

```
public class Outer{
    private Outer.Inner personal;
    public Outer(){
        //processing.
        //personal assigned value
    }
    ........
    private static class Inner {
        private final Set<String> innerPersonal;
        Inner(){
             innerPersonal=new HashSet<>();
             //populate innerPersonal
        }
    }
}
```

I get an object of Outer in my program,
How can I extract **innerPersonal** in my program, using reflection.

Comment: Where do you want to execute your reflection code from Outer or from another class?

Comment: I want to execute reflection code in another class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to execute the code outside `Outer`, you cannot use `Outer.Inner.class` to refer to your `static inner class` as it is `private`, so here I propose an approach that will simply get first the value of the field `personal`, then call `getClass()` on the returned value of the field (assuming that it is not `null`) to finally access to this `inner class` which allows to access also to its field `innerPersonal`.

```
Outer outer = ...
// Get the declared (private) field personal from the public class Outer
Field  personalField = Outer.class.getDeclaredField("personal");
// Make it accessible otherwise you won't be able to get the value as it is private
personalField.setAccessible(true);
// Get the value of the field in case of the instance outer
Object personal =  personalField.get(outer);
// Get the declared (private) field innerPersonal from the private static class Inner
Field  innerPersonalField = personal.getClass().getDeclaredField("innerPersonal");
// Make it accessible otherwise you won't be able to get the value as it is private
innerPersonalField.setAccessible(true);
// Get the value of the field in case of the instance personal
Set<String> innerPersonal = (Set<String>)innerPersonalField.get(personal);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Factory {

            Class<?> value();
    }
```

---

```
public class Outer{
    private Outer.Inner personal;

    public Outer(){
        //processing.
        //personal assigned value
    }
    @Factory(SomeType.class)
    private static class Inner {
        public final Set<String> innerPersonal;
        Inner(){
             innerPersonal=new HashSet<>();
             //populate innerPersonal
        }
    }    


 }
```

---

```
Outer o = new Outer();
Object r = o.getClass().getAnnotationsByType(Factory.class);
```

---

maybe this works.

Comment: I don't see any use of reflection in this answer.

Comment: I cant change structure of **Outer** class

Comment: Sorry I didnt see you wrote "reflection" @user3781866